# Set margin of span if it contains a cetain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

could you help me, please how to:

set a 30px margin to every class="topic_item" span, if the span contains this text "-1-"?

The span looks like this, you can see inside the text "-1-" should trigger the margin:

```
<span class="topic_item">
    <a class='topic-completed' href='http://www.pplkonyv.hu/topic/1-1-1-sebesseg-es-gyorsulas/' title='1-1-1 Sebesség és gyorsulás'>
        <span>1-1-1 Sebesség és gyorsulás</span>
    </a>
</span>
```

Thank you very much in advance

András

Answer (score 0):

You can try jquery for conditional give margin like this

```
$('.topic-completed > span :contains("-1-")').each(function () {
    $(this).css('margin',"30px");
});
```

Comment: Small typo: needs to be span:contains("-1-") without the space

Answer (score 0):

pure js approach;

use filter, includes, map, closest ancestor;

```js
let allInnerSpans = document.getElementsByClassName("innerSpan");

let filteredSpans = Array.from(allInnerSpans).filter((span) => {
 return span.innerHTML.includes('-1-');
});
for(i=0;i<filteredSpans.length;i++) {
filteredSpans[i].closest(".topic_item").style.margin = '30px';
}
```

```html
<span class="topic_item">
    <a class='topic-completed' href='http://www.pplkonyv.hu/topic/1-1-1-sebesseg-es-gyorsulas/' title='1-1-1 Sebesség és gyorsulás'>
        <span class="innerSpan">1-1-1 Sebesség és gyorsulás</span>
    </a>
</span>
```

Comment: Why not chain your calls and replace the `for` loop with a `.forEach` though? Also, the `filter` callback could be written as a one-liner without the need for curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive it using jquery closest and contain.Here is the working code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<span class="topic_item">
    <a class='topic-completed' href='http://www.pplkonyv.hu/topic/1-1-1-sebesseg-es-gyorsulas/' title='1-1-1 Sebesség és gyorsulás'>
        <span>1-1-1 Sebesség és gyorsulás</span>
</a>
</span>
</div>
<div>

<span class="topic_item">
    <a class='topic-completed' href='http://www.pplkonyv.hu/topic/1-1-1-sebesseg-es-gyorsulas/' title='1-1-1 Sebesség és gyorsulás'>
        <span> Sebesség és gyorsulás</span>
</a>
</span>
</div>
<div>

<span class="topic_item">
    <a class='topic-completed' href='http://www.pplkonyv.hu/topic/1-1-1-sebesseg-es-gyorsulas/' title='1-1-1 Sebesség és gyorsulás'>
        <span>1-1-1 Sebesség és gyorsulás</span>
</a>
</span>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('.topic-completed > span:contains("-1-")').closest('.topic_item').css('margin', "30px");
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure Javascript (Vanilla) approach:

```
var topics = document.querySelectorAll(".topic_item");
var searchingTag = '-1-';
for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
  var topicCompleted = topics[i].childNodes[1];
  var yourText = topicCompleted.innerText;
  // indexOf approach
  if(yourText.indexOf(searchingTag) !== -1){
      topicCompleted.style = 'margin-left: 30px';
  }
 }

 //ES6 approach
 // if(topicCompleted.innerText.includes('-1-')) { /*...*/ }



 //RegExp approach
 // var string = topicCompleted.innerText,
 // expr = /-1-/;
 // if(expr.test(string)) { /* ...*/ }
```

JsFiddle here: https://jsbin.com/jukiyuzoli/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

jQuery seemed the simplest:

```
$( "a.topic-notcompleted:contains('-1-')" ).css( "margin-left", "21px" );
```